Sudden Job Contract Termination After Just 8 Days—How Should I Handle This?
I recently joined a European company as a remote software engineer, and after just 8 days, they terminated my contract without any prior warning. It felt like the rug was pulled out from under me—especially after going through three rounds of interviews for a senior position, with the promise of long-term work.
During my short time there, I was assigned three tasks in Jira. Two were non-reproducible, and I was actively working on the third. I even asked for time estimates to set expectations, but none were provided. Then, out of nowhere, they told me my contract was ending that same day.
The contract had a 14-day notice period, which they completely disregarded. Instead, they blamed my performance. But how can you judge someone’s performance after just a week? I was still learning their existing codebase, business logic, and conventions. Sure, I was a bit slower in the beginning, but isn't that normal when starting on a complex enterprise Java codebase? They also criticized me for taking too many meetings to get up to speed, but how else was I supposed to understand their systems and expectations working remotely without some initial guidance?
I’m struggling to understand how they judged my performance in just over a week. If there were concerns about my speed or ability, feedback would have been appreciated, and I would have adjusted. Instead, they ended the contract abruptly without honoring the notice period stated in the contract.
I’m trying to handle this situation professionally, but I’m feeling quite cheated, discrimitated. How should I address this sudden termination, especially considering the lack of feedback and the disregard for the contractual notice period?

There doesn't seem to be much to address you are let go. Everything beyond that seems to be a legal matter and as such off topic here.

"Sure, I was a bit slower initially, but isn't that normal when starting on a complex enterprise Java codebase?" It depends on how experienced you are. You might also determine what the grace period is, in other words, the period of time either party can walk away from the contract.  You might want to check if the 14-day notice go into effect immediately?

The company is based in Europe; are you also living in and working from Europe?

I'm getting the feeling we're not hearing the full story

Were you an actual contractor, paid by the day or hour? Or were you an employee with an employment contract?

In Germany it is called "Probezeit" and can be anything from 2 weeks up to 6 month in which there is no need to give a reason (but they need to give 14 days notice). In Austria the maximum is 1 month for Probezeit, but they dont need to give the notice. It really depends on which country it is

@Zibelas "Probezeit" is an important concept OP should learn about. It's intended literally as a "test run" period where both employee and company can walk away for virtually any reason. It's not unheard-of for companies to cut seemingly underperforming staff aggressively during this time. It's damn hard to fire somebody later, and even harder in a remote job where it's difficult to objectively determine underperformance to the extent that a German labor court would require.

@Zibelas and in the Netherlands there is NO notice period at all during that trial period (the duration of which is dependent on the duration of the contract as a whole, never longer than 2 months).

Concerning the 14-day notice period, check your contract and the employment laws of the country. Most European countries have strong employee-protection laws. If in Germany, for example, there should be no way for them to be getting around this (citing bad performance or so), this is the legal minimum notice period during your trial period (Probezeit), and not honoring it is a rather strong violation. (Only serious offenses like stealing, assault, etc, could be grounds for termination without notice.) They may be trying to bully you into letting it go, because they hope you don't know the law.

What country? For example, in The Netherlands, de "proeftijd" is legally - IIRC - max 1 month for 6 month+ temporary contracts (no "proeftijd" (probation) for shorter contracts!), to 2 months for indefinite contracts, and employment can be terminated immediately without warning or reason by either side within the "proeftijd" (so no notice, contrary to Germany).

The justification provided for closing the topic is misleading. The questioneer asks specific and qualitative question, which can be answered. Also the question is workplace related. Insofar I see the question not being off-topic and well answerable. Also other postings in this community seem to be overdone by closing, which creates the impression of layman censorship.

@Sascha The question is only really answerable if a country is specified and the exact terms of the contract, because if the OP is working in NL, on a temporary 6 month+ or indefinite contract and the probation was included, then there is no recourse for this sudden termination, as it would be perfectly legal. While on the other hand, in Germany, they might need to take action, assuming the employer doesn't pay the two weeks of the notice period.

@MarkRotteveel The title and posting include five questions, which none are exclusively law seeking advice. The question „How should I handle this?“ can be answered in many ways. One way being legal advice of a law academic and other ways being giving advice as a mentor. The question is qualitative and subjective and so will be the answers. Closing this question because it could involve a legal aspect is paranoid.

@Sascha I'm not the one that closed...

As Helena says in comments, there isn't much you can do about the termination. If they want to terminate you they will. I wouldn't put much stock by the reason - there may have been something completely different, like they changed their mind about the project or the CEO's son-in-law decided he wanted the job. In any case you aren't going to get re-hired. "Performance" may be just an attempt to get round the 14 day notice period.
The lack of notice is entirely another matter. Check exactly what is in the contract about termination.  Since this is presumably a substantial amount of money I would 1) check whether the contract allows for immediate termination and under what circumstances 2) if immediate termination is allowed for "performance" ask for details of what led them to this conclusion 3) unless they give something unexpected and satisfactory invoice them for the 2 weeks pay in lieu of notice 4) get the opinion of a lawyer, and tell them you are getting the opinion of a lawyer.
Deal with the department that issued your paperwork, not the boss that fired you if possible. European countries often have small claims courts in which it is feasible to get amounts like this paid without excessive legal fees. The company may very well decide it's cheaper to pay you than have a court battle. It's probably a negiligible amount to them.
By the way, I'm assuming you are an actual contractor. If you are an employee you have a much stronger case.

I agree that nothing much I can do about the termination. My point is just after 8 days terminating in a day notice was that even professional? I have been working for more than 10 years, I have manged people. I know how to address when someone is below par. But putting all the blame on me and firing on the same day seems the hurting point. I think they are doing this several people. I am considering if writing a proper review on glass door would be a right thing or not? What do you think please provide your suggestion

I would not consider this "professional" and would never work for this company again. It's never a bad idea to write a truthful review of your employer on GlassDoor, after you've left. But my answer is intended to indicate that, apart from maybe getting your 2 weeks of pay, there is not a lot to be done. Try what I said; write your review; go have a big drink with a friend and tell them all about it; then look for another job.


You can judge performance of some people in 8 hours.  I don't know if this was the case with you.  No one except the company knows why you were let go.

You mention a contract.  Well, read the contract.  It seems to me you would  be owed 2 weeks of pay.  Your local laws will be a factor.

You move on and find more work.  Put your energy into new employment while working to get what you are owed according to your contract.



About pt2: It could be there is probation in the contract, often a month (at least in NL). The employer and employee can both say "Nope, this is the last day, bye" without any notice.

As Martijn says, in the Netherlands at least there is NO notice period during the probation period. All he'd be due payment for is the actual hours logged during the days he was employed. I've made use of this myself once (as an employee) when discovering in the first week or so how incredibly toxic the work environment at a company was.

-1: Performance of someone can greatly vary day-to-day, and depends heavily on their familiarity with what they're working on. No one will be at their best after just 8 days with a new sizable codebase. This goes for more than just tech: Someone at HR will take time to learn policies and where things are stored, someone in sales will take time to learn the product and the customers.

This will be the 5th answer but I think my content is important.
You have to just move on and put this behind you.  In the software industry, some of those promoted to decision making roles have very low social skills.  In my 30 years as a software dev, I have seen all kinds of low social IQ examples.
The most severe was I worked in a group (in the US) that hired some new to the country Indian contractors.  These dudes were very low paid and had some language issues.  The senior devs looked for any excuse to fire them within the first month of being there.  They ended up firing two in the first month, and I felt that it was unfair.  These senior devs were just jerks and longed to add pain to other peoples' lives.
I would say that completing two stories in 8 days is a good pace.  Even if you did some things wrong, I would want to see how you responded to coaching.  Barring some gross misconduct issues, there is something else going on that you are not being made aware.
Perhaps you remind one of the senor devs of a guy who stole his girl friend.  Perhaps someone wanted to hire a friend instead, etc, etc, etc...  Whatever, it is beyond your control so...
Just update your resume and move on.
It hurts now, but this may be a blessing in disguise.
Once you get into the swing of looking for work you may want to consult with a lawyer to see if you have a breach of contract/wrongful termination case.

This event is hurtful psychologically and financially. I will not second guess myself because:

There were 3 interviews for this position to evaluate your skills;
8 days is very short in a developer existence, it may be the time it take to receive all your access;
There were no on-boarding process because you had to call some meetings about what are the processes, what is the system behavior, etc.

You will never know the source of the issue, it may be caused by:

expectation from the employer seems to be offset without an on-boarding period;
business or financial plan changed;
personality did not fit with the company.

It is hard to protect against this kind of situation, harder for a remote position and plus harder when the employee and the employer are not in the same country.
The available resources are expensive and may not value two weeks of salary.
I feel the solution is "cut your lost", may be send a sign on delivery letter that they own X$, equivalent of two week of work then focus to find a new job.

Yes, it cost me 1.5 months of focus and hard work, If I was incapable I could not have passed all those tests. I felt hurt when I realized they are terminating me on the same day as If I had done some serious misconduct. Do you think adding a glass door review is a good way protect someone from these in future?

It is hard to say. Sure your review will help others because it will spread awareness if there are multiple comments about the same issue. But writing a review is also engaging with the company. They will probably link the bad review to you. They may ping you, it may help you to negotiate with them, like pay me and I will gladly update my review or they can be more drastic, like sending you a lawyer. And Glassdoor is no longer incognito. Glassdoor is require to share the reviewer information now if it is requested from a justice process.

@TomSawyer I think the details of the event being shared on glassdoor would allow the employer to figure out which employee it is anyways. Also if this is a German company, consider kununu in addition to glassdoor.

I want to strengthen the previous comments and say, not much you can do overall.
Decisions often made based on criteria that you do not know
Financially you should check the contract and invoice the 14 work days notice period
Emotionally, however ,there is no much you can do but deal with it by not taking it personally :)

I think you were still in your probation period:

It is a period of time in which both the employer and employee can
assess the suitability of the job and the employee. During this
period, the employer is allowed to evaluate the employee’s performance
and decide whether the employee is a good fit for the job. Yet the
same goes for the employee, they can use this period of time to assess
the company culture and the job.
During the probation period, both the employer and employee have the
right to terminate the employment relationship without notice. This
means that either party can end the contract at any time without the
need for a specific reason or prior notice.


It doesn't matter what you think. Unless your quote is directly from the OPs contract, there is no way of knowing whether this is applicable here or not. It only matters what is in the specific contract and what local labor laws are.

Also being in probation doesn't necessarily mean you can be fired at zero notice.

Actually in most cases it does - that is what the probation is for. No-commitment. It even says so explicitly.

Thanks, TomTom. Given the limited information provided by the OP, my answer appears to be the most plausible. I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted for this.

It is not universally correct. In some european countries you still need to give a notice period during probation but you can still terminate without reason.

Whether or not a probation period can be terminated without any notice or requires a minimum notice depends on the country.
